# Java sound playback and data plot coordination of pre-recorded file

Tags: java, performance, audio, synchronization, javasound

I am trying to write a program that plays a saved .wav audio file, while simultaneusly showing the plot of the sound's amplitude. I use a graphing library (JChart2D) and the Java Sound package to achieve this. The problem is to feed the chart a data point at the same frequency (44100 hz) of the audio so they are coordinated. 
I have tried using the `Thread.sleep()` method, but it is not accurate enough. A 5 minute audio file has a latency of more than 10 seconds at the end.
I also saw an answer on a similar topic suggesting a "busy wait" using `System.nanoTime()`, but that causes an excessive load on the processor (100%).

How can this be achieved? (Maybe with other packages or libraries, altough a suggestion with the curent ones would be preferable).

The data is saved in a byte array, that I passed to a `Clip` for playback, and that I want to feed the graph at 44,100 hz.

Comment: `The Clip interface represents a special kind of data line whose audio data can be loaded prior to playback, instead of being streamed in real time.` It doesn't work with clip. I'm afraid you'll need to use `SourceDataLine` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics are often displayed at a frame rate of something like 60 fps.  So, can you chart 735 ( = 44100 / 60) sound values in one visual frame, or is there a particular need to try and go at the same rate as the audio?

Java isn't big on real time guarantees as far as when it is executing threads, so trying to coordinate two threads is going to be tough. But Java does do a good job with maintaining a steady feed that allows the sound data to play back correctly, thanks to the SourceDataLine's write() method employing blocking.

Using a SourceDataLine would allow you the opportunity to accumulate the sound as it is being played (hence better timing). There is some example code for SourceDataLine that should be helpful at the following link.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html

In the first example there is a point in the code (in a while loop) where we have this comment:

```
  // Here, do something useful with the audio data that's 
  // now in the audioBytes array...
```

That "useful" something would be decoding the bytes to PCM values and accumulating them into an array of something like 735 values for passing over to the graphics thread.